# Restructuring JSON before input

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

Here's an example of object from the JSON output of my database:

```
{
    "id": "http://...",
    "type": "example-type",
    "title": "Example title",
    "container-title": "Example container title",
    "page": "1-100",
    "issue": "3",
    "URL": "http://www.url",
    "ISSN": "0123-0123",
    "author": [
        {
            "family": "Smith",
            "given": "John"
        }
    ],
    "issued": {
        "date-parts": [
            [
                "2000"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "keyword": "Sample Tag"
}
```

I've had enormous difficulties/bugs referring to the nested fields for author and date when building a data table. What I would like to do is somehow modify/flatten this before using it in the table (using Datatables' `dataSrc` as described [here](http://medium.com/code-kings/datatables-js-how-to-modify-your-returned-ajax-json-data-before-sending-it-to-your-html-table-24a92244bc40)) and then simply call the restructured data as many times as I need using the [datatables API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/).

So what I now refer to as `issued.date-parts.0.0` would be simply `year`. The structure would be instead:

```
        "authors": "John Smith", "Mark Smith"
        "year": "2000"
```

Comment: Is there no way to amend the data coming back from the server? That would be the most appropriate place to make these changes. Also note that the structure of `authors` would still need to be an array in your second example.

Comment: If I understood your comment correctly, I can do a `$.get` and try to do this before feeding it to the table. Otherwise I can't really do anything else, as I don't control the JSON file.

Comment: @east1999 do that on your server side.

Comment: @Ele I don't think I have that kind of option here. Would need to have some more server-side languages/tools and I can only run html/javascript.

Comment: Where this data `"year": "1000"` come from?

Comment: "date-parts" has only one position? and the inner array as well?

Comment: It can have two more — year, month, day — but I'm only interested in the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `map` function to get the `authors`

## Look at this code snippet

```js
var data = {    "id": "http://...",    "type": "example-type",    "title": "Example title",    "container-title": "Example container title",    "page": "1-100",    "issue": "3",    "URL": "http://www.url",    "ISSN": "0123-0123",    "author": [        {            "family": "Smith",            "given": "John"        },        {            "family": "Smith",            "given": "Mark"        }    ],    "issued": {        "date-parts": [            [                "2000"            ]        ]    },    "keyword": "Sample Tag"};

var result = {
  "authors": data.author.map((d) => `${d.given} ${d.family}`),
  "year": data.issued['date-parts'][0][0]
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```